# Is there a better, more efficient way to get the post id outside the loop?

Tags: posts, id

Right now I am using:

```
$wp_query->post->ID;
```

I want to know if there is a better way for getting the post id that consumes less resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to your way would be to access the `$post` global:

```
global $post
echo $post->ID;
```

But

1. It won't make a noticeable difference, either way
2. If you want to increase efficiency, you ought to be looking elsewhere...

**EDIT**, pertaining to comments:

> what about `get_the_ID();`?

--> Needs to be run *inside* the Loop.

> i have tried both options (get_the_ID and accessing $post global) both give me a wrong id.

If the latter is the case, you, or some plugin you are using, has not properly [reset postdata](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata).

> You say to look elsewhere... where should I be looking?

I have no idea what it is you are writing. But if you experience resource bottlenecks or inefficiency, retrieval of the current post ID is likely not the cause.

Comment: just checked, so I can safely keep using `$wp_query->post->ID;` ? And, if I want to use your way, I can put `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` before `global $post`

Comment: Well, the resetting of the post global *should* happen *after* whatever secondary loop modified the global. But essentially, yep, your above assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `get_queried_object_id()` in conjunction with `is_main_query()` outside the Loop

```
if ( is_main_query() )
    $mypostid = get_queried_object_id();
```

Note that this function will return author id on a archive page, category id on a category archive, etc.